# How to remove space (before or) after comma from a string?

Tags: python, string, whitespace

How do I remove whitespace before or after comma?
I have tried split(), but I want the result be a string as well.

E.g

string1 = "tree one two, true op op,blue io op"
result = "tree one two,true op op,blue io op"

Comment: have you tried replacing " ,"  to ","  and ", " to "," use the [replace](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_replace.asp) method

Answer (score 1):

lstrip() will remove left blank spaces, rstrip() will remove right blank spaces, strip() will remove all blank spaces.

By the looks of it, [lstrip()](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=strip#str.lstrip) is what you're after.